# Как сделать, чтобы при сохранении файла в sublime он автоматически заливался на сервер?

Tags: sublime-text, fileupload

Всегда пользовался nodepad++ и его ftp плагином который позволял создавать и хранить насколько ftp подключений, удобно если приходилось быстро переключаться между проектами.

Как я понял в сабламе такого нет, и чтобы создать или переключиться между проектами нужно править учетные данные для подключения в конфиге.
поправьте, если чего то не знаю (программой пользуюсь мало.

Хорошо бы иметь какое же ftp окно как в нодпаде.

Пока пользуюсь альтернативой, подключаюсь через файлзиллу и через нее открываю файл в саблайме, но после каждого сохранения приходится приходится переключаться на файлзиллу и перезаливать файл.

Может быть есть способ после сохранения в саблайме делать автозаливку в файлзилле?

Может быть еще есть способ обновлять стили в браузере при нажатии на "сохранить", даже если сайт хранится на сервере без использования node.js?))

Comment: [**Эти**](https://packagecontrol.io/search/sftp) и [**эти**](https://packagecontrol.io/search/filezilla) пакеты пробовали? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных нет, да и про поиск не знал, не думал что менеджер пакетов настолько мощный что там и это есть

Comment: Может, Вам просто достаточно [**Simple FTP Deploy**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Simple%20FTP%20Deploy) — пакета как раз для Вашей проблемы? Но он не интегрирован с FileZilla. Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть еще есть способ обновлять стили в браузере, даже если сайт хранится на сервере без использования node.js?))

Comment: Евгений Шевцов, на мой взгляд, это разные вопросы, их [**не рекомендуется задавать в одном**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3169/199934). По существу: если напишете новый вопрос про обновление стилей, чем больше деталей укажете, тем лучше. Например: какой у Вас браузер — существующие пакеты не для всех браузеров; почему без Node.js, чем это мешает Вам. И я не очень понял, как Вы работаете: если Вы вносите изменения сразу на удалённый сервер, возможно, Вам пригодится [**поиск по ключевому слову remote**](https://packagecontrol.io/search/remote), например, пакет RemoteEdit. Спасибо.

Comment: Ещё [**плагин**](https://github.com/klaascuvelier/SublimeCommandOnSave) нашёл, может, Вам пригодится. Спасибо.